# Limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} (\log(x)\log(1-x))$ with $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1,1\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1,1\}$.

We want to find out the limit of this (if it exists):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} (\log(x)\log(1-x))$$

I have seen the following from another post, but I don't quite understand it.

> First make the substitution $u=1-x$. The limits comes down to
> $$\lim_{u\to 0^+}\ln(1-u)\ln u$$
> Now $\;\ln(1-u)\sim_0-u$, so that
> $$\lim_{u\to 0^+}\ln(1-u)\ln u=\lim_{u\to 0^+}(-u\ln u)=0.$$

He substitues $u = 1-x$.

How does that lead to $\lim_{u\to 0^+}\ln(1-u)\ln u$?

If we "reinsert" $1-x$, that leads to $\ln(1-1-x)\ln 1-x$ which makes no sense to me.

Comment: $$\ln(x)\ln(1-x)\mathop=^{u=1-x}=\ln(1-u)\ln(1-(1-u))=\ln(u)\ln(1-u)$$ Then expand $\ln(1-u)\approx\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{u^n}n$, so the $k=1$ approximation is $\frac{u^1}1=u\approx \ln(u)$

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks. And how does $\ln(u)\ln(1-u)$ lead to $-u \ln u$?

Comment: Your reinsertion is missing brackets: you want $\ln(1-(1-x))\ln(1-x)$, which is indeed $\ln (x)\ln (1-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick to deal with this kind of limit calculations:

$$\begin{align}
L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \ln(x)\cdot\ln(1-x)&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(x\cdot\ln(x)\cdot\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\right)\\
\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(x\cdot\ln(x)\right)\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\right)\\
\\
\text{Let} ~~~x=\frac{1}t~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~&=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{t}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\right)\\
\\
\text{Use L'Hopital's Rule} ~~~~~~&=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{-\ln(t)}{t}\right)\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\right)\\
\\
&=0\cdot(-1)=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: when you let $x=\frac{1}{t}$ did you not substitute it into the second limit?

Comment: No, only sub to the first limit. Because the second limit is already good to do L'Hopital's rule. @HossienSahebjame

Answer (score 1):

Just use
$\log(1-x) \approx -x
$ as $x \to 0$.
Then you want
$\lim_{x \to 0} -x \log(x)
$.

Setting $x = 1/y$, this becomes
$\lim_{y \to \infty} -\frac1{y} \log(\frac1{y})
=\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac1{y} \log(y)
=\lim_{y \to \infty} \log(y^{1/y})
$.

Using any of the usual proofs that
$y^{1/y}\to 1$
or
$n^{1/n}\to 1$
shows that this is zero.